# Reloading table view and swiping right to delete

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, timer

I am reloading table view every 0.25 seconds as I have a timer app, but the delete button when I swipe from right to left won't stay there because I am reloading the table view.

How do I fix this?

Comment: "I am reloading table view every 0.25 seconds" it seems really surprising to me! Not sure if you are really need such a behavior.

Comment: How else will I update the time labels in the table view - it would really help me if you could tell me! :)

Comment: So you might need to mention exactly what's the purpose of it...

Comment: even if it's a chat app 0.25 is weird

Comment: I am making a timer app Sh_Khan

Comment: Ahmad F the purpose is to change the time left on the countdown timer in the table view once the date subtraction has taken place

Comment: You can simply iterate over the visible cells (which you can find from the tableview) and then update the cell contents directly. No need to reload.

Comment: Could you please describe this in a more detailed way Paulw11? - maybe even post it as an answer and I will tick it right if it helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to `reload` the `tableView` to update the visible cells.  Instead, loop over the visible cells calling the update method on each one:

```
// Example custom cell class
class MyCustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    func updateTimeLabel() {
        // code to update time label
    }
}
```

In the timer method:

```
for case let cell as MyCustomCell in tableView.visibleCells {
    cell.updateTimeLabel()
}
```

Your `updateTimeLabel` method might need data such as the current `Date` or the new value for the time label, so pass it what it needs to update the label.

Comment: Reason for the downvote?  Constructive criticism please.  I can't improve the answer without feedback.

Answer (score 0):

a start of solution could be to observe swipe events on tableview thanks to :

```
optional func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
```

in this func you stop the reload func

and in :

```
optional func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
```

you restart your reload func